# In R: How to replace NA in a Vector found between two integers

Tags: r, vector

I have the following vector:

```
A:(NA NA NA NA 1 NA NA 4 NA NA 1 NA NA NA NA NA 4 NA 1 NA 4)
```

I would like to replace all the Nas between 1 and 4 with 2 (but not the Nas between 4 and 1)

Are there any approaches you would recommend/use for this task?

It may also be managed as a dataframe:

```
 A 
----
 NA 
 NA 
 NA 
 NA 
 1 
 NA 
 NA 
 4 
 NA 
 NA 
 1 
 NA 
 NA 
 NA 
 NA 
 NA
 4 
 NA 
 1
 NA 
 4
----
```

**Edit**:
 1. I changed the string "Na" to NA.

**SOLUTION/UPDATE**
Thank you to everyone for your insights. I learnt from them to come up with the following solution to my case. I hope it is useful to someone else:

```
A <- c(df$A)

index.1<-which(df$A %in% c(1)) # define location for 1s in A
index.14<-which(df$A %in% c(1,4)) # define location for 1s and 4s in A

loc.1<-which(index.14 %in% index.1) # location of 1s in  index.14
loc.4<-loc.1+1 # location of 4s relative to 1s in index.14

start.i<-((index.14[loc.1])+1) # starting index for replacing with 2
end.i<-((index.14[loc.4])-1) # ending index for replacing with 2 in index

fill.v<-sort(c(start.i, end.i))# sequence of indexes to fill-in with # 2

# create matrix of beginning and ending sequence
fill.m<-matrix(fill.v,nrow = (length(fill.v)/2),ncol = 2, byrow=TRUE) 

# create a list with indexes to replace
list.1<-apply(fill.m, MARGIN=1,FUN=function(x) seq(x[1],x[2])) 

# unlist list to use as the indexes for replacement
list.2<-unlist(list.1) 

df$A[list.2] <- 2 # replace indexed location with 2
```

Comment: There is currently no `NA` in the question. Do you mean the string `"Na"`?

Comment: Please note I meant```NA``` and not the string ```"Na"```.
Thank you all for the correction and also the suggested methods.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `A` is as shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, the difference of cumsum's shown gives TRUE for the elements between 1 and 4 inclusive and the next condition eliminates the endpoints.  Finally we replace the positions having TRUE in what is left with 2.

```
replace(A, (cumsum(A == 1) - cumsum(A == 4)) & (A == "Na"), 2)
```

giving:

```
 [1] "Na" "Na" "Na" "Na" "1"  "2"  "2"  "4"  "Na" "Na" "1"  "2"  "2"  "2"  "2" 
[16] "2"  "4"  "Na" "1"  "2"  "4"
```

### NA values

R is case sensitive and Na is not the same as NA.  The sample data in the question showed Na values and not NA values but if what was actually meant was  a numeric vector with NA values as in `AA` in the Note below then modify the expression to be as shown here:

```
replace(AA, cumsum(!is.na(AA) & AA == 1) - cumsum(!is.na(AA) & AA == 4) & is.na(AA), 2)
```

giving:

```
[1] NA NA NA NA  1  2  2  4 NA NA  1  2  2  2  2  2  4 NA  1  2  4
```

### Note

```
A <- c("Na", "Na", "Na", "Na", "1", "Na", "Na", "4", "Na", "Na", 
"1", "Na", "Na", "Na", "Na", "Na", "4", "Na", "1", "Na", "4")

AA <- as.numeric(replace(A, A == "Na", NA))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's a better solution to this problem but this should do the trick:

```
A <-
  c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, 1, NA, 4)

replace <- FALSE

for (i in 1:length(A)) {
  if (!is.na(A[i])) {
    if (A[i] == 1) {
      start <- i + 1
      replace <- TRUE
    }
    if (A[i] == 4 & replace == TRUE) {
      A[start:(i - 1)] <- 2
      replace <- FALSE
    }
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT:** if you only want to replace the NAs if there's nothing else (for example a 3) between the 1 and the 3 you could use this:

```
A <-
  c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 3, 4, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, 1, NA, 4)

replace <- FALSE

for (i in 1:length(A)) {
  if (!is.na(A[i])) {
    if (A[i] == 1) {
      start <- i + 1
      replace <- TRUE
    }
    if (A[i] == 4 & replace == TRUE) {
      A[start:(i - 1)] <- 2
      replace <- FALSE
    }
    if (A[i] != 4 & A[i] != 1){
      replace <- FALSE
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
> A
 [1] NA NA NA NA  1 NA  3  4 NA NA  1  2  2  2  2  2  4 NA  1  2  4
```

---

And if you only want to replace NAs but keep other values between 1 and 4 use this:

```
A <-
  c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 3, 4, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, 1, NA, 4)

replace <- FALSE

for (i in 1:length(A)) {
  if (!is.na(A[i])) {
    if (A[i] == 1) {
      start <- i + 1
      replace <- TRUE
    }
    if (A[i] == 4 & replace == TRUE) {
      sub <- A[start:(i - 1)]
      sub[is.na(sub)] <- 2
      A[start:(i - 1)] <- sub
      replace <- FALSE
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
> A
 [1] NA NA NA NA  1  2  3  4 NA NA  1  2  2  2  2  2  4 NA  1  2  4
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work as well and I assumed you were referring to `NA`'s and no the string `"Na"`. It would work for either though (or a mix).

```
> A <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, 1, NA, 4)
> 
> btw_1_4 <- unlist(lapply(Map(`:`, which(A == 1), which(A == 4)), function(x) x[2:(length(x)-1)]))
> 
> A[btw_1_4] <- 2
> 
> A
 [1] NA NA NA NA  1  2  2  4 NA NA  1  2  2  2  2  2  4 NA  1  2  4
```

`Map(`:`, which(A == 1), which(A == 4))`

Creates a list of positions for 1-4 ranges in the vector (in order)

`lapply(Map_List, function(x) x[2:(length(x)-1)])`
Removes the first and last element of each vector in the list (the position of 1 and 4)

`unlist` makes all the remaining positions (`NA`'s between 1 and 4) a single vector

Comment: Hi Andrew, I was wondering if you could help me out. I'm using a vector of length 1:4096 and running into the following error when using ```Map(`:`, which(A == 1), which(A == 4))``` :

```Warning message:
In mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) :
  longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter```

Comment: Hey Anthony, in the context of the above example, it looks like there at least 1 instance of a repeated 1 or 4 (i.e., `c(NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, 4)` or `c(NA, 1, NA, 4, 4, NA, 1)`. What do you want to do in this case? Looks like another answer already has a solution but the other ones are certainly adaptable.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you for following up. In that scenario I am interested in replacing the NA with 2 only for conditions that have ```1 NA 4```. so in the second example I would not replace NA for ```4 NA 1```.

Comment: Sure thing! One more clarification: do you want to change the second or first `1` to NA for this vector: `c(NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, 4)`, and do you want to change the second or first `4` in this vector `c(NA, 1, NA, 4, 4, NA, 1, NA, NA, 4)`?

Comment: Thank you for asking. It is not necessary. For this I only need to change the appropriate NAs.